# Geodatabase add current date and time to attribute

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, time, date

Is it possible in Arcmap 10.0 to create a geodatabase feature class that has a date field which auto populates with the current date and time, every time a new feature is created? Is this possible without programming? Have checked ESRI help but nothing. The feature class is not in ArcSDE so it is not versioned.

Comment: This became easy at 10.1 where you can **enable editor tracking** but that was not available until then.

Answer (score 1):

The code attached in here might help you: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/9374-Timestamper-for-ARCGIS-10

Comment: I tried using the .bat file but i get operation failed. Maybe its to do with privileges on win XP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

[Timestamper class extension](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISDesktop/dotnet/C16F2960-9A7D-4d46-8966-A27CCF9BF1A9.htm)

Comment: Hi Jeff, please provide context for external links, as noted in the community help page:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer